# How to parse data from a CLOB in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, clob, openrowset

I would like to use OPENROWSET with the BULK command to load data into SQL Server as a CLOB, and as a second step to parse the CLOB and load read the data as a table.

E.g.:

```
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\somedir\somefile.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) TheFile
```

yields:

```
BulkColumn
Col1,Col2,Col3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3
```

I want to select this as:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
1      2      3
1      2      3
1      2      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx) and use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) or [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to import data from text file.
Example format.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1" /> 
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1" /> 
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1" /> 
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Col1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" /> 
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Col2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" /> 
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Col3" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" />  
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

This is the key line:
`<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="1" />`
where the terminator char is "," and not "\r\n", if the data is in a single line.

Example OPENROWSET:

```
INSERT INTO [your_table]
SELECT      [text_file].[Col1],
            [text_file].[Col2],
            [text_file].[Col3]
FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK N'c:\somedir\somefile.txt',
FORMATFILE = N'c:\somedir\format.xml',
FIRSTROW = 1) AS [text_file]
```

Example BULK INSERT:

```
BULK INSERT [your_table]
FROM        N'c:\somedir\somefile.txt'
WITH        (FORMATFILE = N'c:\somedir\format.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't import it as `OPENROWSET..BULK`

You can use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to import it as columns or [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) by itself

Comment: I could, but they also cause other problems.

Comment: @Karl: well, it is the correct way to do it. Why import it as one then split it up? It makes no sense. Alternatively, improve your question as to *why* you need to import as a LOB...